# Function call stack: test_function -> test_function -> test_function on GPU but not on CPU

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

While doing a text classification task using word embeddings and a 1 layer BiLSTM, i get this error message. I only get it on GPU but not on CPU. On CPU, i get a SIGKILL even before the model is compiled.  I cant seem to figure out what trigers it. Any ideas?

```
WARNING:tensorflow:AutoGraph could not transform <function Model.make_test_function.<locals>.test_function at 0x7fe40471f790> and will run it as-is.
Please report this to the TensorFlow team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output.
Cause: Bad argument number for Name: 4, expecting 3
To silence this warning, decorate the function with @tf.autograph.experimental.do_not_convert
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 50) for input Tensor("embedding_input:0", shape=(None, 50), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 1).
2020-11-14 20:16:16.215514: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-11-14 20:16:17.104192: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1753] OP_REQUIRES failed at cudnn_rnn_ops.cc:1517 : Unknown: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM
in tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc(1496): 'cudnnSetRNNDataDescriptor( data_desc.get(), data_type, layout, max_seq_length, batch_size, data_size, seq_lengths_array, (void*)&padding_fill)'
2020-11-14 20:16:17.105991: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1753] OP_REQUIRES failed at cudnn_rnn_ops.cc:1517 : Unknown: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM
in tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc(1496): 'cudnnSetRNNDataDescriptor( data_desc.get(), data_type, layout, max_seq_length, batch_size, data_size, seq_lengths_array, (void*)&padding_fill)'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "WordEmbedding_LSTM.py", line 262, in <module>
    history = model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=100, verbose=False, batch_size=100, validation_data=(val_y, val_y),callbacks=[es, mc]) 
  File "/usr/pkg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 66, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/pkg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 862, in fit
    val_logs = self.evaluate(
  File "/usr/pkg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 66, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/pkg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1081, in evaluate
    tmp_logs = test_function(iterator)
  File "/usr/pkg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 580, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/pkg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 650, in _call
    return self._concrete_stateful_fn._filtered_call(canon_args, canon_kwds)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/usr/pkg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1661, in _filtered_call
    return self._call_flat(
  File "/usr/pkg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1745, in _call_flat
    return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
  File "/usr/pkg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 593, in call
    outputs = execute.execute(
  File "/usr/pkg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 59, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError:  [_Derived_]  CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM
in tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc(1496): 'cudnnSetRNNDataDescriptor( data_desc.get(), data_type, layout, max_seq_length, batch_size, data_size, seq_lengths_array, (void*)&padding_fill)'
         [[{{node cond/then/_0/CudnnRNNV3}}]]
         [[sequential/bidirectional/backward_lstm/StatefulPartitionedCall]] [Op:__inference_test_function_18103]

Function call stack:
test_function -> test_function -> test_function
```

Here is my model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size,
                    output_dim=embedding_size,
                    weights=[w2v_weights],
                    input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
                    mask_zero=True,
                    trainable=False))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(100, dropout=0.2)))
model.add(Dense(n_categories, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: I removed ```mask_zero=True ``` argument and its not bringing up this error anymore.

Comment: And for this warning  ```  WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 50) for input Tensor("embedding_input:0", shape=(None, 50), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 1). ``` , i passed in the validation label as the validation data mistakenly.